# PHP - update query using postman return success but not update the value in database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582472/php-mysql-update-success-but-database-not-updated) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322909/pdo-update-returns-success-but-doesnt-update-the-database) but not yet finding a solution

I've function update like this :

```
 public function updateArtist($id, $name, $genre){
 $stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE api SET name = ?, genre = ? WHERE id = ?");
 $stmt->bind_param("sss",$id, $name, $genre);
 if($stmt->execute())
 return true; 
 return false; 
 }
```

and the index of update is :

```
 case 'updateartist':
 if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['genre'])){
 $db = new DbOperation(); 
 if($db->updateArtist($_POST['id'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['genre'])){
 $response['error'] = false;
 $response['message'] = 'Artist updated successfully';
 }else{
 $response['error'] = true;
 $response['message'] = 'Could not update artist';
 }
 }else{
 $response['error'] = true; 
 $response['message'] = 'Required Parameters are missing';
 }
 break;
```

I'm using postman to try, and here is an output of postman that show success message :

[image: success]

but when I check mysql, the value not change,

did I missing something?

Comment: UPDATE Statement is also successfully if no record is found. Check the number of effected rows

Comment: @Jens i've check the number of effected rows, but still displaying an old value

Comment: And i guess the number of effected rows is 0 and why you can read in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of your the binded parameters must be the same as the order in your query.
Use `s` for `string`, `i` for `integer`, `d` for `decimal` and `b` for `blob` while binding the parameters.

```
public function updateArtist($id, $name, $genre){
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE api SET name = ?, genre = ? WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $name, $genre, $id);
    if($stmt->execute())
    return true; 
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: good information sir, I really want to know what the meaning of `char` inside `"` mark. +1, but i don't know why when i didn't change the `"sss"` the script still updated the value

Comment: *why when i didn't change the "sss" the script still updated the value* because mysql will automatically convert the string to an int. it is the same as you write `where id='1'`

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE` Statement is also successfully if no record is found. Check the number of effected rows.

The order or the pastameter you bind is importend. Change to:

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE api SET name = ?, genre = ? WHERE id = ?");
 $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $name, $genre,$id);
```

In your code the id will be bind to the first question mark, so it is bind to `name` and so on.

Comment: i though it's doesn't matter where you put the field inside bind, so i need to insert the param in sequence. thanks, *__I can't mark as answer for now__*

Comment: because of your reputation is most higher than @Spectarion, i think i will give the mark to him, :) , thanks anyway

Comment: @RedRiver You should not look at the Reputation you should think about which answer is more helpful.. But anyway it is ok